# Do Christians receive the same inheritance as Messianic Jews?

Tags: protestantism, eschatology, new-earth, nations

I know that in Christ there is complete redemption for both Jew and Gentile but it seems as though God has made specific promises to the house of Israel and that God throughout the bible shows special affinity toward Israel.

The promise of Israel was that they would rule all the nations from Jerusalem and that all the material blessings of God will flow from Israel to the other nations.

God also refers to Israel as his firstborn among the nations and according to the royal pattern God has set, the first born always receives the largest inheritance among his siblings.

So in patristic perspective, do the Jews in Christ receive a particular inheritance while Gentiles also receive a great yet definitively different inheritance?

The Jews in Christ will inherit the land of Israel. Will Gentiles rule in Israel with Jews or will Gentiles inhabit / rule their own respective nations in Christ, i.e Russia, China, Central African Republic, Japan, Germany, India, etc.? What is the protestant view on this?

Comment: Can you please edit this to add capital letters? And unfortunately there is no single protestant view. I'd recommend asking for either the pre-millennialist or a-millennialist view.

Comment: Answerers should probably be experts in _supersessionism_ and _dual-covenant theology_.

Comment: Two House theology would have something to say as well? After all, Joseph and thereby Ephraim inherit the name Israel. They were then split from Judah and divorced (Zech 9, Jer 3:8) Ephraim is then scattered to the nations (Isaiah 46) where he will be regathered from when it is time to reunite Judah and Joseph (Ez 37). They are resurrected and united under his servant David, planted in the land and God's sanctuary is in their midst forever. Sounds familiar to Rev 21? Romans 9-11? The Gentiles (Joseph) are co heirs of those promises going all the way back to the covenant with Abraham.

Answer (score 2):

Most Christians will likely agree on the basic principle that the Children of Israel, down to the present day have a special relationship with God, but that at this stage, we don't know what that relationship is, exactly. Jesus' parable of the workers in the vineyard (cf. Matthew 20:1 ff.) might apply here, with the Children of Israel representing those hired earlier in the day, and Gentile Christians representing those hired at the eleventh hour. On the other hand Paul taught the Galatians (3:28-29) that there is "neither Jew nor Greek, slave nor free, male nor female, for you are all one in Christ Jesus. And if you're Christ's, then you are Abraham's offspring according to the Promise." [RSV]

Besides, Jesus was a Jew. Christians believe nearly universally that we are part of the Body of Christ, which makes us Jews, too.

By the way, it should be noted that depending upon their exact beliefs, most [Messianic Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Jews) would be considered Christians.

Comment: Excellent response.  Only thing I might suggest is finding a different word than "mystical" to define the spirit of Christ.  Too many link that word to the occult.

Comment: Very cool answer. Never thought I would see anything like it on this site. Wish I could give you +100.

Comment: How has this answered the question?

Comment: I have to downvote this for two reasons. 1. The parable in Matt 20 implies people hired at all times get the same reward; your "on the other hand... neither Jew nor Greek" seems to imply otherwise. 2. Though Christians believe themselves to be "the Body of Christ", I don't see how that makes us Jews.

Comment: @Wikis Re 2, there is a widespread notion among the Christian churches that the _Remnant of Israel_ and the _Body of Christ_ are synonymous. This is the doctrine of _supersessionism_, and it is a source of ambiguity in the meaning of the word _Jew_. Modern Christians certainly don't engage in Jewry or Judaism.

Comment: Answering a broad quesion like this without even mentioning the spread from dispensationalism to covenant theology is a huge oversight and turns this into a truth debate rather than a documentation of 'Christian' beliefs.

Comment: @Andrew I strongly disagree that one has to believe in supersessionism to believe that the church is the remnant of Israel. The stick of Joseph (among the nations/goyim) will be joined to the stick of Judah (the Jews).

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee That's not what I said. Conversely, one has to believe  that the Church is the remnant of Israel to "believe in supersessionism". But doctrines are not things that we "believe in". They are things that we teach. If one teaches that the Church comprises the elect, then that teaching is generally referred to as supersessionism. The point of my comment is to say that since " the children of the promise are counted for the seed", then the Church is counted as the seed of Abraham. It was meant to respond to Wikis' statement  "I don't see how that makes us Jews."

Answer (score 0):

God does in fact have a special relationship with the Jewish people. That special relationship stems from the fact that Israel is God's chosen nation (the nation through  which God would bring Salvation to the world).

And Looking back at History we find that that relationship began with Abraham:

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation unless otherwise noted.

> Genesis 15:3 through 6  And Abram said, Behold, to me thou hast given no seed: and, lo, one born in my house is mine heir. And, behold, the word of the LORD came unto him, saying, This shall not be thine heir; but ***he that shall come forth out of thine own bowels shall be thine heir***. And he brought him forth abroad, and said, Look now toward heaven, and tell the stars, if thou be able to number them: and he said unto him, So shall thy seed be. And he believed in the LORD; and he counted it to him for righteousness.

But Abraham had a elderst child through Sarah's handmaiden.

> Genesis 16:15  And Hagar bare Abram a son: and Abram called his son's name, which Hagar bare, Ishmael.

But God did not choose Abraham's elder son as his chosen Nation.

> Gen 17:18 through 22  And Abraham said unto God, O that Ishmael might live before thee! And God said, Sarah thy wife shall bear thee a son indeed; and thou shalt call his name Isaac: and I will establish my covenant with him for an everlasting covenant, and with his seed after him. And as for Ishmael, I have heard thee: Behold, I have blessed him, and will make him fruitful, and will multiply him exceedingly; twelve princes shall he beget, and I will make him a great nation. But my covenant will I establish with Isaac, which Sarah shall bear unto thee at this set time in the next year. And he left off talking with him, and God went up from Abraham.

God again  chose not to continue his chosen Nation through the eldest son:

> Gen 25:21 through 26  And Isaac intreated the LORD for his wife, because she was barren: and the LORD was intreated of him, and Rebekah his wife conceived. And the children struggled together within her; and she said, If it be so, why am I thus? And she went to enquire of the LORD. And the LORD said unto her, Two nations are in thy womb, and two manner of people shall be separated from thy bowels; and the one people shall be stronger than the other people; and the elder shall serve the younger. And when her days to be delivered were fulfilled, behold, there were twins in her womb.   And the first came out red, all over like an hairy garment; and they called his name Esau. And after that came his brother out, and his hand took hold on Esau's heel; and his name was called Jacob: and Isaac was threescore years old when she bare them.

In each of these cases what we find is that God deliberately chose the ones who would best serve him. This remained true throughout the history of the Jewish nation. Some examples are Jacob (Israel), Joseph, and David.

God has never abandoned the Nation of Israel, however he has put conditions on their prosperity:

> 2nd Chronicles 7:14  If my people, which are called by my name, shall humble themselves, and pray, and seek my face, and turn from their wicked ways; then will I hear from heaven, and will forgive their sin, and will heal their land.

That promise is still in effect today, but it no longer pertains only to Israel:

> Matthew 23:37 and 38  O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, thou that killest the prophets, and stonest them which are sent unto thee, how often would I have gathered thy children together, even as a hen gathereth her chickens under her wings, and ye would not! Behold, your house is left unto you desolate.

We learn from this Scripture that because of the repeated ignoring of the prophets, the promise of Salvation no longer is exclusive to the Jewish Nation:

> John 10:14 through 16  I am the good shepherd, and know my sheep, and am known of mine. As the Father knoweth me, even so know I the Father: and I lay down my life for the sheep. And other sheep I have, which are not of this fold: them also I must bring, and they shall hear my voice; and there shall be one fold, and one shepherd.

From this we learn that Jesus intended to include other Nations in Salvation, and that would consist of those whom he knew and they knew him. This may be thought of as the basis for Salvation and is why we are to confess Jesus as our Lord and savior.

If Jesus meant that there should be separate rewards for Jew and Gentile why would he have said:

> Mark 16:15  And he said unto them, Go ye into all the world, and preach the gospel to every creature.

Comment: I have to disagree with *"the promise of Salvation no longer is exclusive to the Jewish Nation"*. I don't think it ever was; see eg [Numbers 15:15-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+15%3A15-16&version=NIVUK).

Comment: @Wikis While you are correctly reading that Foreigners living among them were subject to the same laws and etc., That was still restricted to the Nation of Israel, and as I understand what Jesus said in Matthew 23:37 and 38 that was when the other nations were included. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I don't think Jesus' words in Mat 23 at all imply any exclusivity to salvation. Indeed, I'm sure God's grace extends to people *before* Abram, eg Noah.

Comment: @Wikis I agree with your concept that God's grace certainly applied to Noah and generations both before and after him (Enoch is an example), but that was before initiation of the Mosaic laws and the sacrificial system. Again please correct me if I am misreading the Scriptures!

Comment: We should probably take this to chat... :)

Comment: @Wikis Chat is not an option for me since being blind the process of reading and writing is long and laborious for me.

Comment: OK, what I wrote in chat was: "The Law is not a means of salvation but a way to point out our sin. (Romans 8:3) Now I think about it, I don't think the Law was ever intended to bring us salvation because it can't. There's only Grace - Amazing as it is." We can set up a dedicated chat room or leave it there... your choice.

Comment: @Wikis as much as I would like to continue this, you would bet bored very fast as do others when I try to chat.  There seem to be some things that we will only know when we get to ask in person, providing they still interest us.

Comment: Up to you; but if you mean people get bored because of the speed, I *can* handle this speed of communication if you can.

Comment: Answering a broad quesion like this without even mentioning the spread from dispensationalism to covenant theology is a huge oversight and turns this into a truth debate rather than a documentation of 'Christian' beliefs.

Comment: @Caleb I do not know about many other denominations, but as a Baptist we believe that the Holy Bible is the inerrant word of God, and it seems that if I give the Scriptures which cover the question; I am giving at least our 'Christian' beliefs. As with Wikis above disagreement with my understanding of the Scriptures is surely questionable, but are the Scriptures able to speak for themselves. All modern Christianity is based on one interpretation or another. Please correct me if I am wrong!